# Hadoop Pseudo-Distributed Operation error: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type

Tags: hadoop

I am setting up a `Hadoop 2.6.0` Single Node Cluster. I follow the [hadoop-common/SingleCluster documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). I work on `Ubuntu 14.04`. So far I have managed to run Standalone Operation successfully.

I face an error when trying to perform **Pseudo-Distributed Operation**. I managed to start NameNode daemon and DataNode daemon. **jps** oputut:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
4963 SecondaryNameNode
4785 DataNode
8400 Jps
martakarass@marta-komputer:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

But when I try to make the HDFS directories required to execute MapReduce jobs, I receive the following error:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
15/05/01 20:36:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "marta-komputer/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000; 
martakarass@marta-komputer:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

(I believe I can ignore the `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...` warning at this point.)

---

When it comes to `Hadoop` config files, I changed only the files mentioned in the documentation. I have:

**etc/hadoop/core-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I managed to connect to localhost:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:~$ ssh localhost
martakarass@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Fri May  1 20:28:58 2015 from localhost
```

I formatted the filesystem:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:/usr/local/hadoop$  bin/hdfs namenode -format
15/05/01 20:30:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = marta-komputer/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
(...)
15/05/01 20:30:24 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at marta-komputer/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

**/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       marta-komputer

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**etc/hostname**:

```
marta-komputer
```

Comment: Try change `defaultFS` property from `localhost` to `marta-komputer`

Answer (score 4):

This is a set of steps I followed on Ubuntu when facing exactly the same problem but with `2.7.1`, the steps shouldn't differ much for previous and future version (I'd believe).

#### 1) Format of my **`/etc/hosts`** folder:

```
    127.0.0.1    localhost   <computer-name>
    # 127.0.1.1    <computer-name>
    <ip-address>    <computer-name>

    # Rest of file with no changes
```

#### 2) `*.xml` configuration files (displaying contents inside `<configuration>` tag):

- For **`core-site.xml`**:

  ```
      <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
      </property>
      <!-- set value to a directory you want with an absolute path -->
      <property>
          <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
          <value>"set/a/directory/on/your/machine/"</value>
          <description>A base for other temporary directories</description>
      </property>
  ```
- For **`hdfs-site.xml`**:

  ```
      <property>
          <name>dfs.replication</name>
          <value>1</value>
      </property>
  ```
- For **`yarn-site.xml`**:

  ```
      <property>
          <name>yarn.recourcemanager.hostname</name>
          <value>localhost</value>
      </property>

      <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
          <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
      </property>
  ```
- For **`mapred-site.xml`**:

  ```
      <property>
          <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
          <value>yarn</value>
      </property>
  ```

#### 3) Verify `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`:

This is a good opportunity to verify that you are indeed using this configuration. In the folder where your **.xml** files reside, view contents of script **`hadoop_env.sh`** and make sure `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is pointing at the right directory.

#### 4) Check your PORTS:

NameNode binds ports **50070** and **8020** on my standard distribution and DataNode binds ports **50010**, **50020**, **50075** and **43758**. Run `sudo lsof -i` to be certain no other services are using them for some reason.

#### 5) Format if necessary:

At this point, if you have changed the value `hadoop.tmp.dir` you should reformat the NameNode by `hdfs namenode -format`. If not **remove** the temporary files already present in the tmp directory you are using (default `/tmp/`):

#### 6) Start Nodes and Yarn:

In **`/sbin/`** start the name and data node by using the **`start-dfs.sh`** script and yarn with **`start-yarn.sh`** and evaluate the output of jps:

```
    ./start-dfs.sh   
    ./start-yarn.sh
```

---

At this point if NameNode, DataNode, NodeManager and ResourceManager are all running you should be set to go!

If any of these hasn't started, share the log output for us to re-evaluate.

Comment: Hi Jim, as per your step no 4 i checked my port but i can see 50070 as LISTEN but didn't find 8020. Can you help me how can i add it.

Answer (score 1):

remove    `127.0.0.1       localhost` from `/etc/hosts`
and change your `core-site.xml` like follow:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://marta-komputer:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and you can ignore the `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...` warning

Comment: Hi @Yosr , thank you for your answer! I followed your suggestions, reformatted the filesystem and now the error is as followed: `java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "marta-komputer/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "marta-komputer":9000; ` Where else should I make a change?

Comment: could you browse the web interface for the NameNode which is http://marta-komputer:50070/ ??

Answer (score 1):

Do these changes in **/etc/hosts**:

**1. Change:**

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    marta-komputer
```

to one line

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    marta-komputer
```

**2. Delete:** (if exists)

```
127.0.1.1    marta-komputer
```

**3. Add:**

```
your-system-ip    marta-komputer
```

To find your system IP, type this in terminal

```
ifconfig
```

(find your IP address here) or type this:

```
ifdata -pa eth0
```

Your final **/etc/hosts** file should look like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       marta-komputer
your-system-ip       marta-komputer

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Change **hdfs-site.xml**:

**1. Change:**

```
hdfs://localhost:9000
```

to

```
hdfs://marta-komputer:9000
```

Now, stop and start hadoop processes.

Your **jps** command should list these processes:

```
Namenode
Datanode
TaskTracker
SecondaryNameNode
```

If it does not list all these processes, check respective logs for errors.

**UPDATE:**

1. Follow this tutorial [here](http://pingax.com/install-hadoop2-6-0-on-ubuntu/)
2. If the problem persists, it might be due to permission issue.

**UPDATE II:**

1. Create a directory and change permissions for namenode and datanode:

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hdfs/namenode`

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hdfs/datanode`

`sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hdfs/namenode`

`sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hdfs/datanode`

2. Add these properties in `hdfs-site.xml`:

`dfs.datanode.data.dir` with value `/usr/local/hdfs/datanode`

`dfs.namenode.data.dir` with value `/usr/local/hdfs/namenode`

3. Stop and start hadoop processes.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, thank you for the answer! In my case `ifconfig eth0` looks like [this](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1YIX) and hence the `ifdata -pa eth0` returns `NON-IP`. How do you think this matters to my problem?

Comment: Does `ifconfig` returns your IP?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, I'm sorry for my mistake (lookin for an IP in `eth0` paragraph), of course `ifconfig` returns my IP. I made all the updates and I have now: [/etc/hosts](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11029897/), [etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1YJ5), [etc/hadoop/core-site.xml](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1YJ4). Running `sbin/start-dfs.sh` generates [such output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11029849/). After this I call `jps command` and receive [such output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11029851/). It seems there is no `Namenode` (and `TaskTracker`) ...

Comment: ... but I see nothing wrong in `Namenode`-related log files: [hadoop-martakarass-namenode-marta-komputer.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11029872/) and [hadoop-martakarass-namenode-marta-komputer.out](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11029863/). I have also noticed that when I try to browse the address from the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation): `Browse the web interface for the NameNode; by default it is available at: NameNode - http://localhost:50070/`, I see `This webpage is not available`.

Comment: I have reinstalled Hadoop, performing all the configurations steps from the tutorial. It seems I have a problem with `NameNode` setup: when I run `sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `sbin/start-yarn.sh` I see [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11039817/) similar to that from tutorial, but the `jps` suggests **NameNode is not running**. Also I can see web view of `ResourceManager` but page for `NameNode` – localhost:50070 - stays not avaliable. Stopping `sbin/stop-dfs.sh` and `sbin/stop-yarn.sh` also [suggests](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11039883/) there is no `NameNode` and `DataNode` to stop.

Comment: Did you format `namenode`? Post `namenode` and `datanode` logs.

Comment: I keep formating namenode after each config change. Here come: `namenode` format [console output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11042790/), `start-dfs.sh`,`start-yarn.sh` and `jps` [console output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11042804/) and **logs**: `hadoop-hduser-namenode-marta-komputer.out` [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11042840/), `hadoop-hduser-namenode-marta-komputer.log` [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11042869/), `hadoop-hduser-datanode-marta-komputer.out` [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11042875/) and `hadoop-hduser-datanode-marta-komputer.log` [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11042879/)

Comment: Post your `core-site.xml` file. Did you change `localhost` to `marta-komputer` in core-site.xml?

Comment: I have not changed it since I followed the tutorial. Now I changed and have such ([core-site.xml](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11046157/)). I formatted the `namenode` and run `jps`, receiving such [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11046176/) (`namenode` is still not appearing). Please note I keep having `/etc/hosts` like you advised me ([see here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11046211/)) and the other `hadoop` config files are like in [tutorial](http://pingax.com/install-hadoop2-6-0-on-ubuntu/) you linked (except from the `core-site.xml` file I mention and show above).

Comment: Thank you for the second update! I removed Hadoop temp directories for Namenode and Datanode I created while following [the tutorial linked](http://pingax.com/install-hadoop2-6-0-on-ubuntu/) and create them again, accoriding to your instructions. I changed `hdfs-site.xml` into [this](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1YKZ), stopped processes, reformatted the `NameNode` and run the processes again. Unfortunately, `jps` says the `Namenode` is still not running - [see the console output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11057665/). I think I am going to issue a separate question for this `Namenode` issue...

Answer (score 0):

i got this error once when i was uploading files to hdfs from java code ,The issue was that i was using hadoop 1 jar to connect to hadoop 2 installation,not sure whats the problem in your case but if you ever configured hadoop 1 eariler then something must be messing with it