# Hadoop: namenode starting and then getting off suddenly,not showing in jps

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to create a cluster for using hadoop. I am trying to start my namenode but it is not starting. After restarting the system it starts for a moment and then again goes off.I am using the command as a root user and given the namenode the root user rights. I am facing the same problem with jobtracker and datanode.
To start the namenode I am using the command `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`
What is the problem here?

```
[hadoop@localhost ~]$ hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode

starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop- namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

[hadoop@localhost ~]$ jps
6500 Jps
[hadoop@localhost ~]$ jps
```

The core-site.xml file contains

```
<configuration> 
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name> 
<value>hdfs://lab1:8020</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

The hdfs-site.xml contains

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication.dir</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to clarify the question a bit.

What is the mode you are trying to deploy hadoop with? Also, please provide the output of the command for us to see.

Comment: @DimitrisJim I am trying to create a pseudo distributed mode.

Comment: <[hadoop@localhost ~]$ hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

[hadoop@localhost ~]$ jps
6500 Jps
[hadoop@localhost ~]$ jps
>

Comment: The full output is not visible, edit your original post accordingly to display it? Also, check (and provide) your namenode log file so we can see what's making it crash.

Comment: @DimitrisJim How to get the namenode log file?

Comment: It displays it when you run your command :). Here /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/

A small walkthrough of how I set up my pseudodistributed cluster can be found here if you want to take a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992952/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-operation-error-protocol-message-tag-had-invalid-wire/32041603#32041603)