# ConnectException: Connection refused when running mapreduce example

Tags: hadoop

I am started learning Hadoop. I followed this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm

When I am trying to execute the below command

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduceexamples-2.2.0.jar  wordcount input output
```

getting this error

```
17/05/23 10:11:50 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
java.net.ConnectException: Call From LAPTOP-9BNLKT1E/192.168.1.11 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992952/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-operation-error-protocol-message-tag-had-invalid-wire/32041603#32041603

Comment: @philantrovert I am using windows machine. I couldn't not find **/etc/hosts** folder

Comment: I believe its in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` for Windows.